# Trying to understand the cause of the leak?

Tags: motorcycle, leak

I am preparing to jump into a change of my stator (generator) on a 2007 DL1000 Suzuki V-Strom. I saw something unusual on the outside of the box, can anyone determine whether this might indicate a leak from the stator or some other part of the bike?

I've just received all of the parts (gasket and stator kit) so before I get started just wondering if this should give me pause to review anything else? I've already swapped out the rectifier/regulator.

[image: stator-box]

Comment: It could just be that the bolts to the area are not as tight as they used to be, or that something is getting worn out. In the Army, we would call this a "Class I" leak ... there is evidence, but it's all just seepage. I would bet this is going to need to be regasketed in order to solve the issue, but I'm not a MC expert, so there you go.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for the feedback. I'll try swapping out the generator with the new gasket tomorrow and then I'll have a better idea.

Comment: I know this is obvious, but clean the area up really well when you do. It will make it easier to see if there is new leakage or not. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and easy industry method for determining sources of leaks is to clean the suspected area thoroughly with heavy degreaser (brake cleaner, carb cleaner, kerosene) and then spray the suspect area with Tough Actin' Tinactin. Start the motorcycle and let it warm to operating temperature. Keep a close eye on the area you just sprayed. The tinactin will discolor the moment it comes in contact with any type of liquid.